# Can I bring my girlfriend to Germany for 6 months?

Tags: germany, eu-citizens, study, students

I'm a Greek PhD student living and studying in London. In one year from now I am required to do a "secondment" in a certain university in Germany which has a six-month duration. Having a Greek passport means that I'm a EU/EEA citizen. My girlfriend is also Greek with a Greek passport. We are not married.

My question is the following: Can I bring my girlfriend to Germany for the 6-month duration of my secondment without any restrictions? Will she be allowed to stay for this long, without having a job, just being my partner?

Comment: Technically she has a right to stay without conditions for up to 90 days.  To stay longer, she has to show that she can support herself, or that she is your "partner in a durable relationship."  Which route to choose probably depends on how she's planning to support herself, whether through her own savings or your finances.

Comment: @phoog Where can I find concrete information on the "partner in a durable relationship" part?

Comment: Directive 2004/38/EC, the freedom of movement directive.  I'll post an answer in a bit.

Comment: I've been working on an answer, but i cannot find enough unambiguous information online.  Here's a link for the directive: http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616. The actual administration is done at the local level; as an example, here's a link for the relevant page of the Berlin Ausländerbehörde: https://www.berlin.de/labo/willkommen-in-berlin/freizuegigkeit-eu-ewr-schweiz/. The upshot seems to be that you will be fine just registering, but I can't find any unambiguous confirmation of that.

Comment: See also http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/moving-to-germany-with-fianc%c3%a9e-both-eu-citizens-because-of-work-reasons-what